# Can you install subclipse and subversive in the same Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I just installed Fedora 14 and I see that it includes Eclipse 3.6.

It would be easier for me to just use the version Fedora includes, but it seems to force me to use Subclipse for SVN support.  I really like Subversive better.

Can they co-exist or am I going to run into all kinds of trouble?
I'd prefer to not just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can co-exist, but that will lead to duplicate context-menu entries with identical labels. You will often have to guess which is which.

Comment: yuck!  Maybe I'll just try out subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with Juno.  Had Subversion installed and installed Subclipse.  The right-click context menu in any history view was the Subversion, um, version, so I'm going to say "no".  Also, uninstalling Subversion turned out to be impossible for me even with manual deletions of the associated jars.  Be prepared to re-install Eclipse.